# What is the smallest counting number you can create higher than 1?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

What is the smallest integer you can create using 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 that is **strictly greater than 1**?

- You can use any mathematics symbol.
- You must use all nine numbers.
- You can't use the same number more than once.
- You can't use the same mathematics symbol more than once.

Comment: "*You can use any mathematics symbol*" - you need to narrow this to a finite list. Otherwise I can just invent a mathematical symbol $*$ and define it almost however I want. There are a LOT of mathematical symbols out there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the distinction "counting number" which refers to the natural numbers, i.e. positive integers. Here they are equivalent, since we only consider numbers greater than 1. I don't think there was any ambiguity in that part of the original statement.

Comment: Adding to @votbear 's answer, if the smallest number we could make it *not* strictly greater than $1$, but still is greater nonetheless, then it would be as follows: $$\frac{1}{2\times 3\times 4\times 5\times 6\times 7\times 8\times 9} = \frac{1}{9!}$$ Through multiplication, it will be using $\times$ more than once, but we can write the denominator as $9!$ which is an alternative mathematical symbol that is only used once so....

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Uh...

> The smallest integer which is strictly greater than 1 is 2, right?

Which is achievable by many means, one of which is

> 2 + (18 / 3 - 6) * [the rest of the numbers here]

Comment: `You can't use the same mathematics symbol more than once.` How would you add the rest of the numbers ?

Comment: @Doomenik By concatenating the remaining numbers to 14579. That is if concatenating is allowed, otherwise this solution is invalid.